# Make rails 3 jquery autocomplete working for an integer column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, autocomplete

I wonder why rails 3 jquery autocomplete gem doesn't work in an integer type of a column.

I have a column name code btw.

```
autocomplete :category, :code
```

The code is integer but whenever i try to implement autocomplete, it isn't working.

Tried `cast_to_text` solved by an issue participant: https://github.com/greg-barnett/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/13d20b087f261690553dff268ff39bb6893ddaa3/lib/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/orm/active_record.rb

But I don't understand how to really use it, because it is not working also.

View:

```
<%=f.autocomplete_field :category_id, autocomplete_category_code_project_procurement_management_plans_path, class:'cat-code',:full => true%>
```

PS: code is my self declared primary key.

```
set_primary_key "code"
```

That is why, I really need to change code to integer, but seems like Autocomplete is not compatible with it.

According to the "inspect element" feature of Chrome.

Network Log:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at
>   /project_procurement_management_plans/autocomplete_category_code==================================================================================================> PG::Error: ERROR:  function lower(integer) does not existLINE 1:
>   SELECT  categories.code FROM "categories"  WHERE (LOWER(cate...
>   ^HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.: SELECT  categories.code FROM
>   "categories"  WHERE (LOWER(categories.code) ILIKE '100%') ORDER BY
>   categories.code ASC LIMIT 10(gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb,
>   line
>   291---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------`ruby  286             raise exception  287           end  288     289 
>   def translate_exception(e, message)  290             # override in
>   derived class> 291
>
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid.new(message)  292           end  293
>
>   294       end  295     end  296   end`App backtrace-------------Full
>   backtrace-------------- - (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:291:in
>   `translate_exception' - (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1145:in`
>   translate_exception' - (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:284:in
>   `rescue in log' - (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in`
>   log' - (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:661:in
>   `exec_query' - (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1248:in`
>   select' - (gem)

And so on.

Any workarounds will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error message closely, you'll see that the problem is in this SQL:

```
SELECT categories.code
FROM "categories"
WHERE (LOWER(categories.code) ILIKE '100%')
ORDER BY categories.code ASC
LIMIT 10
```

In particular, PostgreSQL doesn't like that LOWER call:

> function lower(integer) does not exist

There are two problems in the generated SQL there if `categories.code` is a number:

1. You can't LOWER a number, downcasing a number doesn't make any sense.
2. You can't ILIKE a number, LIKE and ILIKE are for strings.

Reading [the code](https://github.com/greg-barnett/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/13d20b087f261690553dff268ff39bb6893ddaa3/lib/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/orm/active_record.rb) suggests that using the `:cast_to_text` option would result in a query like this:

```
SELECT categories.code
FROM "categories"
WHERE (LOWER(CAST(categories.code AS TEXT)) ILIKE '100%')
ORDER BY categories.code ASC
LIMIT 10
```

That would convert `code` from a numeric value to a string and you can LOWER and ILIKE strings to your heart's content.

So how do we use `:cast_to_text`? The [fine manual](https://github.com/greg-barnett/rails3-jquery-autocomplete#options) includes this example for the `:full` option:

```
class ProductsController < Admin::BaseController
  autocomplete :brand, :name, :full => true
end
```

So presumably you could:

```
autocomplete :category
autocomplete :code, :cast_to_text => true
```

and things would work. You might also notice that the manual doesn't mention `:cast_to_text` along with the other options so you might need to patch that in yourself.

I don't use this gem myself so there is some guesswork going on here.

---

Why the autocomplete gem is downcasing the column **and** performing a case-insensitive pattern match is a mystery. We can safely shake our heads at the strangeness of it all and pretend we didn't see it though.